# How to run a custom loss function in “debug mode” and put breakpoints in it?

Tags: debugging, tensorflow2.0, training-data, loss-function

Using model.fit(), I'd like to execute a customer loss function step by step in a debugger, but the execution does not stop on breakpoints.

```
    tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)

    def mse_loss(y, ŷ):
        return tf.reduce_mean((ŷ - y) ** 2) # <====BREAK POINT
    
    
    model.compile(
        loss=mse_loss,
        optimizer="adam",
        run_eagerly=True
    )
    
    model.fit(x=x, y=y, batch_size=16,
              epochs=3000,
              verbose=1)
```

Using a train_step also does not work:

```
 def train_step(self, data):
        x, y = data

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            ŷ = self(x, training=True)
            loss = self.compute_loss(y=y, y_pred=ŷ)
        ....
```

Is coding my own training loop the only way to debug a loss function in context ?